# Is it not many variety or not much variety?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Is it very confusing when we have to decide ***many*** or ***much*** on things we're not sure whether it's countable or cannot be counted. *Money* can be counted, but still it is with *much*? So who decides the logic?

Comment: There needs to be a distinction between count / noncount usages, and etic denumerability. One has to learn those cases where logic is overriden by usage. //  'There are cattle in that field: I can count ten cows.' ['cattle' is noncount (*3 cattle), taking a plural verb form]. / 'The police were taking their time.' / '10 miles is quite a hike.' / 'There is cutlery in the top drawer'  ['cutlery' is almost always noncount (*3 cutleries), etically denumerable (3 knives and two forks), but taking a singular verb form]. // Here, _variety_ can be used in count or noncount mode.

Answer (score 0):

In most senses, the word "money" is uncountable, [as Wiktionary states](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/money#Noun).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that *money* is uncountable is very natural and 'logical' to a native speaker, just as it is very natural for my mother tongue to have it as a countable noun.

As for ***variety*** there is a logic to it:

1. After *many* you can't have singular nouns (see [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Much-Many-Count-Nouns-and-Mass-Nouns#:%7E:text=When%20using%20much%2C%20the%20noun,much%20and%20many%20are%20used.) or [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers))
2. If *variety* means

> *the quality or condition of being diversified or various* ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/varieties))

then it is uncountable, just like ***not much kindness***, ***not much beauty*** - ***not much variety***.

3. If however it means

> a different form or kind within a general category; sort OR a variety show ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/varieties))

then it is countable and you can say

> - *not many varieties* of behaviour
> - *not many varieties* on TV this week.

[Wiktionary](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/variety#:%7E:text=(uncountable)%20Variety%20is%20the%20quality,shop%20has%2025%20tomato%20varieties.) is not a very popular dictionary here, but it's right on this one. [OxfordLearner'sdict](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/variety) gives a clear explanation also.